# Can I define a shared memory buffer, pass it to sub-processes and use it in an API call?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

I would like to define memory buffers in Python as arrays which are passed to a C function as an array of pointers. The C function fills the buffer with data before returning.  The C API is the dll for access to an ETTUS B210 software defined radio which I have wrapped using ctypes.  I have simplified the code below just to show the essentials of what I am trying to do.

I have this working in a single thread but cannot achieve the same thing if the buffer is defined in a main thread and the API call is in a separate process.  At first sight multiprocessing.RawArray is what I need but I cannot find a way to get access to the underlying data memory as a pointer which I can transfer in the call to the C function.

I need to use multiple processes partly because the C API (not written my me) for the hardware only handles one hardware device at a time but can have multiple instances running.

The reason I handle the buffers this way way is mainly speed - the arrays can be quite large >2000000 floats and are used over and over again so I would like to allocate once and reuse.  Passing data through pipes from one process to another is a giant bottle neck - although it does sort of work.

As a single thread I do something like this:

```
    def stream(n_samples, buffer1, buffer2):
        buffer_list = (c_void_p*2)()
        buffer_list[0] = cast( pointer( buffer1 ), c_void_p ) 
        buffer_list[1] = cast( pointer( buffer2 ), c_void_p ) 
        windll.myapi.stream(c_int(n_samples), byref(buffer_list))

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        buf1 = ( c_float * ( 2*n_samples))()
        buf2 = ( c_float * ( 2*n_samples))()
        stream(n_samples, buf1, buf2)
```

If `stream()` is now part of a process, I tried this but it does not do what I want:

```
        buf1 = RawArray('f', 2*n_samples) 
        buf2 = RawArray('f', 2*n_samples) 
        p1 = process(target=stream, args=(n_samples, buf1, buf2,))
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
```

Although the API seems to be filling memory somewhere (and not throwing an exception which is what usually happens when I get the pointer definitions wrong) it is not accessible through the `buf1, buf2` objects.

As an appendix:  I am using several buffers and in the single threaded version I define one large buffer then calculate offset pointers to pass to the API.  It would be useful to do this in the multiprocessing version but not necessary.

Comment: The calls to `pointer`, `c_int`, and `byref` aren't required, but this *should* work. It works when I substitute `ctypes.memmove`, which is implemented using an FFI call to the libc function. I initialized `buf1` to all 3s in the parent process; copied `buffer1` to `buffer2` in the child; and printed `buf2` in the parent after `p1.join()`. It works as expected. What you want to avoid is passing pointers between processes, which won't work since they're unrelated address spaces.

Comment: @eryksun - very good point.  I just tried invoking `windll.msvcrt.memcpy`  to copy from one array to another in a sub process with no issue. I didn't expect to find python broken but this confirms I'm doing something stupid or it's very subtle.

Comment: Problem fixed - RawArray works fine in this application.  @eryksun suggestion about using another c routine to demonstrate the capability allowed me to remove the complication of the external library from debugging the Python at which point I found an error in setting up the external device.  Passing pointers to shared memory using RawArray was not the problem.